# Problems with curl under macOS Monterey

Tags: curl, zsh, macos-monterey

We have a problem with curl. Under Big Sur, the command

```
curl 'ftp://ftp.myserver/myPath/my File' -u 'myusername':'mypassword' 
properly downloads the file.
```

Under Monterey, the same command throws an error:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

The behaviour is the same, whether the command is issued in Terminal, or as a shell script in a Applescript application created in XCode.

Also note that the username/password combo does work, as it does properly download the list of the directory.

Any advice, workaround etc. is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `my File` with `my%20File`? Spaces aren't legal characters in URLs.

Comment: The same error is thrown when the file name does not contain spaces.

Comment: A workaround I am trying out is replacing the problematic curl commands with wget.